# qpid-cpp-server 1.39.0 will not start on Centos with error qpidd: symbol lookup error: /lib64/libqpidcommon.so.2:

Tags: centos7, qpid, qpid-proton

On Centos7, the qpid-cpp-server has been installed

1. epel package has been installed
2. yum install qpid-cpp-server qpid-tools

The server will not start with error :
qpidd[22202]: /usr/sbin/qpidd: symbol lookup error: /lib64/libqpidcommon.so.2: undefined symbol: _ZNK5boost15program_options22error_with_option_name23substitute_placeholdersERKSs

I have tried installing other packages there error persists.

Comment: It cant find boost, or libboost, or whatever on centos. Install missing packages.

Comment: boost-dev package and libboost are installed.